# Swift import two modules with same name

Tags: ios, swift, import

For an iOS app I use the [Charts library from Daniel Gindi](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts). I am currently migrating from UIKit to SwiftUI and would like to use iOS Charts from Apple which is available from iOS 16 onwards. The app targets iOS 15 + which forces me to keep Daniels Charts library also.

So basically I have two modules with the same name and concerning import statements cannot differentiate between the two. What can I do?

Comment: How about creating an umbrella framework for Daniel Gindi's Charts? You can call that whatever you like.

Comment: I think you might be out of luck. Having googled the problem, the only option I can see is to fork one of the packages and then rename the clashing module.

Comment: I thought so, but wanted to ask anyway. thank you guys.

Answer (score 1):

[Module aliases](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0339-module-aliasing-for-disambiguation.md) we’re added 5.7 which exactly handle this situation.

Comment: https://forums.swift.org/t/how-to-use-the-new-module-disambiguation-in-xcode-projects/58402 says we can't do it yet through Xcode :(